# Using libssh C++ wrapper

Tags: c++, libssh

Anyone here have experienced libssh [C++ wrapper](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__ssh__cpp.html) yet? You can get [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/libssh) I'm using 0.6.3 version . I follow [INSTALL](https://github.com/ajaxorg/libssh/blob/master/INSTALL) instruction in downloaded file to build libraries.

Then I try to compile the example in examples directory [libsshpp.cpp](https://github.com/ajaxorg/libssh/blob/master/examples/libsshpp.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <libssh/libsshpp.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
  ssh::Session session;
  try {
    if(argc>1)
      session.setOption(SSH_OPTIONS_HOST,argv[1]);
    else
      session.setOption(SSH_OPTIONS_HOST,"localhost");
    session.connect();
    session.userauthAutopubkey();
    session.disconnect();
  } catch (ssh::SshException e){
    std::cout << "Error during connection : ";
    std::cout << e.getError() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

by command  `g++ -o sh libsshpp.cpp -lssh` successed but when execute it take error : `./sh: symbol lookup error: ./sh: undefined symbol: ssh_userauth_publickey_auto`. Hope who worked with libssh can help!

Comment: It's a bad idea to call your executable `sh`: That is the name of the system shell.

Comment: I've tried another name but still get same error.

Comment: One thing which might happen is that the `ssh` installed in your system uses another version of the library which doesn't contain that symbol, and your program finds that one on execution. In which case you might be able to fix that with an appropriate `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (but then, that may break the installed `ssh`). Another option would be to try static linking (at the cost of making your executable much bigger).